# Bluetooth mesh, one client many servers, how many elements required?

Tags: bluetooth, element, mesh-network

I want to set up a Bluetooth mesh with one client and 30+ servers.  The client needs to individually address each of the servers.

Is it possible for the client to have just one element that each of the clients subscribes to?  The client would need a way to identify each of the servers. Or does the client need to have a separate element for each of the servers and address them individually using each of the elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use single client and set publishing address for each of servers individually. This means you would need to change publish address each time to send something to the particular server.

If you are using Nordic SDK, you probably would be interested in this [discussion](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/44994/sending-messages-to-unicast-addresses/192879#192879).